# Is it possible to get Commodore 128's Basic v7 emulation to work in Ubuntu?

Tags: emulation

I have installed VICE and it seems to work nicely as far as running Commodore 64 games and programs, and I have not tried testing to see if the basic v4.0 is functional in itself, but any searches for suggestions to make use of Commodore 128 features only point to installing or configuring C64 functionality. All references to C128 functions seem incomplete or non-functional.

Is there any way possible to get VICE running as a C128 Basic V7.0 emulator for use of the sound envelope and video geometry functions?

If not, are there any other c128 emulators available for Ubuntu which are able to emulate C128 basic in the traditional 80 column mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VICE` is a fantastic emulator, even for C128. Unfortunately the documentation is abysmal, because there is heaps of information for specialists, geeks and freaks, but essential information is hidden away somewhere between 3.14.17 and 3.14.18. (At a point where the common reader has already given up...)

It's actually pretty simple:

1. Press <kbd>F7</kbd> on your PC keyboard to switch between 40 and 80 column mode.
2. Perform a hard reset by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>.

Now you will notice that the second window (note that in `x128` there are **two**) has come to life, with a neat 80-column display.

Hope this helps.

Additional note: I've just verified again. Alas, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> is a very bad default choice in Linux, as this key combination is frequently taken by window managers! Hence, invoking a hard reset via this key combination may not work, respectively may not have the desired effect! 
So should it fail for you too, then please invoke the hard reset via drop-down menu: *File -> Reset -> Hard*. This is *guaranteed* to work no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the GRAPHIC command rather than a key combination:

GRAPHIC 0
switches into 40 column mode

GRAPHIC 5
switches into 80 column mode

I wholeheartedly agree with @syntaxerror about F7 and ALT+F12 being a really bad choice for anything other than PC systems. I have the same issue on my Mac, on which the F-keys are actually mapped to the original Commodore F-keys (so F7 simply displays the LIST command, rather than executing the host system's F7 key). Somehow my Mac is stuck in 80 column mode when VICE boots. While I love it, I have no idea how to toggle at boot time